# Once reached last page, Python Selenium Script to continue instead of wait indefinitely

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to click all next pages until last page which it does successfully on this [website](https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/en/football-betting-1/15).  However, it reaches the last page and then waits indefinitely.   How can I best achieve this script to then proceed to the rest of the script once it reaches the last page?  I could do an explicit wait time of 15 seconds timeout but this feels very slow and not the best way of doing this.  Thanks
Full [code](https://pastebin.com/TL6Hz5A4)

```
i = 1
while i < 6:
    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        #time.sleep(random, 3)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,  ".name:nth-child(1)")))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".name:nth-child(1) , bf-coupon-table:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(1) .matched-amount-value"))
        scroll = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".coupon-page-navigation__label--next")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", scroll)
        link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[href^=http://somelink.com/]')
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a")))
        NextStory = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a')))
        link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('bf-coupon-page-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a')
        NextStory.click()
    except:
        i = 6
```

Comment: I think unless you can find a stable way to check on the page if it's the last one, you will have to do some sort of wait, then just catch the timeout exception and break the loop. But maybe you don't have to wait a full 15 seconds?

Comment: @crunker99 Any idea on how I can best achieve this?  I am look at the css selectors and href and they cannot distinguish between when it is last page and 2nd last easily

Comment: I get 403 Forbidden when I go to the url you posted

Comment: @crunker99 You will need an australian vpn -> https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/en/football-betting-1/6

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting to the except block, otherwise the loop would stop.

I think that this line is causing the slowness:

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", scroll)

That is bacause all your other actions are driver actions with timeouts. Try clicking on the webpage and then just click page down key in a loop:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
# Click on a static element in your page
for _ in range(100):
    driver.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```